# Remove obsolete beta version from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

About two years ago I published a version of one of my apps as a beta testing version for a limited number of users, using the "Beta" version in Google Play Developer Console. I didn't promote that version to production, instead I just released another version in the production track.

That old beta is still lingering around, and I can't find a way to get rid of it. I even got an email from Google today saying

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> This is a reminder that starting November 1, 2018, updates to apps and
>   games on Google Play will be required to target Android Oreo (API
>   level 26) or higher. After this date, the Play Console will prevent
>   you from submitting new APKs with a targetSdkVersion less than 26.
>
> Configuring your app to target a recent API level ensures that users
>   benefit from significant security and performance improvements, while
>   still allowing your app to run on older Android versions (down to the
>   minSdkVersion).
>
> **Action required**
>
> Please ensure that your apps are configured to target at least Android
>   8.0 (API level 26) by November 1, 2018. For technical advice on how to change your app's target API level to meet these requirements, refer
>   to the migration guide.
>
> **Affected apps**
>
> The apps included below have one or more APKs—in production or testing
>   tracks—that aren't currently targeting API level 26 or higher. Apps
>   are listed with the maximum version code and corresponding
>   targetSdkVersion. If you have more than 20 apps that could be affected
>   in your account, please check the Play Console for a full list.
>
> com.mypackage.myapp          73     23

The app referred to on the bottom line is the two year old beta version, with a version number of 73 and targeting API 23. The one in production was updated just a few days ago and targets API 28.

Is there any way at all to get rid of that old beta version from Google Play Developer Console?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Using a few hints you left on your stack overflow profile I think I've deduced what your app is and what is the problem. I won't mention the app name here as you seemed to want to keep the question general.

The problem is the *subtle* difference between a **superceded** release and a **shadowed** release. Your beta APK is **partially shadowed**. The beta APK is targeted at users on SDK9+, whereas your production APK is targeted at users on SDK16+. This means while most users will get your production APK, users on older devices (SDK 9-15) will get your beta. As a result, your beta is still technically active, and so you getting the email is correct.

So now the question is what can you do to deactivate it? The answer is a bit confusing in the UI, but makes sense once you think about it. You need to

- create a release with **NO** (0!) APKs in it
- publish that release to the beta track

This tells Play that you deliberately want there to be no active APKs in Beta. These users will still get production APKs, but your old beta APK will no longer be active. We're sorry this got confusing, you were caught by a subtle edge case.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! Now it says "Superseded by production" on the Beta track.

Comment: I was also caught by a subtle edge case.

Comment: _create a release with NO (0!) APKs in it_ unbelievable. Thank you. Would never have figured this out.

Comment: Don't forget that the Alpha and Beta channels may be the case for violation of Google Play policies, for example, if you 'forgot' there some old version with sensitive permissions since 'good old times' when they were eligible.

Comment: I'm not able to create a release with 0 APKs. On clicking review button, I'm getting error - "Your release must have exactly one default flavor artifact." Any idea what is the issue?

Comment: Google Play won't let you create a release with no apk...
Really nice solution - wished it actually worked though :(

Comment: It's still working for me. I just created a new beta release with no apk on it. It does have some warnings and you must enter a name (I entered "0", I don't know if it matter). Save, submit, then the beta release is gone and it said "Superseded by production". Btw, this kinda a weird way to remove it, I mean a button said "Stop Beta" may just better.

Comment: @Jacob.B You can't create a release to production without an APK but you can create a release to beta without an APK - you just need to make sure to set the release name as it doesn't let you use a blank name.

Comment: After two years this is still the only way to remove a beta version. No deactivate button added. Unbelievable.

Comment: Just to mention, this is still The Only Way to remove old beta!

Comment: `reate a release with NO (0!) APKs in it unbelievable.` does still work? why it has to be so not obvious? many users just randomly join to beta and then they have old version for many time and don't receive updates, Google did a really bad job here

Comment: Seems your solution doesn't work anymore in the latest version of Google Play Console. I   added new release without apk and named 1.0 (thought production version is higher) but it's just a string, not a build code... After review it now reports that `1.0` `Release not live`, so beta didn't become suppressed by production version after these steps and it is still available and anyone can join beta from Google Play app...

Answer (score 11):

Just for information of anyone visiting this thread, here is what I did to stop beta appearing on my Google Play Store app listing.

At first, we launched with releases on beta track. Then, when the app was stable with enough feature set, we decided to go for full production. We decided to promote the latest beta release to production track (note we didn't place any apk/bundle on production track just promoted the beta release to production). Then we started to place every new release apk/bundle on production track and this gave us *Superseded by production* on beta track.  But still we faced the issue of ***{App Name} (Beta)*** appearing in the application title on Google Play Store listing.

Then to remove this ***(Beta)*** from application title we had to go into Google Play Store App listing -> Release Management -> App Releases -> Beta Track -> Click on Manage Testers -> Click on Remove Testers. A confirmation dialog will open then click "Yes".

Removing the testers solved the problem.

Comment: It only shows the (beta) mark for people who are beta testers. Clicking on "leave beta" will also remove the sign.

Comment: @Joran tell that to users, they not very smart and usually many of them randomly join beta not really understand why that do it, you comment here is really weird

Comment: There is no such option as "Remove Tester" in the latest version Play Console...

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you had released beta app (Open testing) with v1.0.0, but your production is pointing to newer version. Now you want to discontinue that beta programme having older app.

I have found two ways of discontinuing beta programme in new updated play console.

1. Go to Open Testing settings of your app. You can see the countries where your beta programme is available. Now unselect all the countries except one country as one country is mandatory. For that mandatory conutry, you can keep any country which you feel like that country is not required for you app.
2. Release a new version in Open Testing track with no apk or bundle in it. Yes you can! Play console will allow you to release new beta version without having any app in it.

Answer (score 3):

For new console -

1. Go to open testing.
2. Click on the pause track button in the upper right corner.
3. Click on the pause track button on the confirmation dialog.
4. Congratulations beta version is no longer available to download!

Comment: no longer, but what about old users on this beta?  i want them to update to production version and seems we should do `create a release with NO (0!) APKs in it unbelievable.`, so in this case you SHOULD NOT pause track!!

Comment: My app was new and didn't had many downloads so this was the best option for me. Also you can unselect all countries and choose one random unknown country which you don't specifically target. This blocks all other countries from accessing your beta.

Answer (score 1):

We also see such unobvious behavior but it was about **inner testing track.** Even if you remove user or clear the whole list of users - it doesn't help, and that removed user still see the beta version of the app.

So what we tried and it helps us a lot of times:

- remove list of testing users at all(previously you can copy/export that as backup)
- upload new csv list of users

Answer (score -3):

You cannot delete an app once its published as beta, or alpha or production. Because Play store wants to keep app id as unique, so there will not be conflict if you later wanted to release beta version to production.

The only way you can do is unpublish the app.

Comment: you can not delete the hosted application, but you can pause the track of beta testing, so testing will no longer available for the applicantion.