# how to resolve google play warning regarding "Use of SMS or Call Log permission groups"

Tags: android, permissions, google-play-console

I have removed sms and call log permissions from my app and using alternatives to common uses that is using share intent and dial intent. But I am still getting the same warning in the play console on my application. following is the list of permissions in my app.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Push Notification Permission -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.onwaycab.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission 
     android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<!-- MAP Permission -->
<permission
    android:name="com.onwaycab.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.onwaycab.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Edit:

I am receiving the warning even if I have not used sms and call log permission so it is not duplicate of that question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I getting "SMS and CALL\_LOG permissions warning"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954921/why-i-getting-sms-and-call-log-permissions-warning)

Comment: Check your merged manifest, via the Merged Manifest tab in Android Studio's manifest editor. Perhaps the permissions are coming from a library.

Comment: I have checked Merged Manifest tab but I am not able to find sms or call log permission. kindly tell what else should I do?

Comment: My app is also using GCM and i have not yet update to FCM. I am guessing if this is the issue? can you tell?

<receiver
            android:name="com.mylibrary.pushnotification.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.onwaycab" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: Did the warning show permanently before you managed to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My playstore console showed this "SMS & CALL_LOGS" related warning.

So, I removed the SMS & CALL_LOGS related permissions from the manifest and uploaded the latest release build to playstore. But the warning was still shown to me after latest build was published on store.

So ,After this I filled this below Permissions declaration form and the warning is removed now.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCnRaa4b1VuHhE4gVekWJc_V0Zt4XiTlsKsTipTlPg5ECA7Q/viewform

Comment: I am getting same message while I uploaded new apk after remove all sms permission from menifest and java run time code both.

Comment: please fill in the above form as well in the link

Comment: Did the warning show permantently even after refreshing the site before you removed the permission?

Comment: @Panther yes.  warning was showing after the permissions were removed. BUt then I submitted this above form and it was removed without uploading a new build

Answer (score 6):

If you are seeing this alert every time you refresh the page, then one or more your libraries might be using the permission.

To check all permissions your app is using, just install the app on the real device and check the **App Info** - **Permissions**.

Alternatively, add this to your Manifest file. `tools:node="remove"` will remove the permission in case if any library is requesting it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" tools:node="remove" />
```

Another important point, if you are using build variant then define it inside  your highest priority manifest file.

- Library manifest: lowest Priority
- Main manifest: Medium Priority
- Build Vairant manifest : Highest priority

Answer (score 1):

Another thing worth checking - we had an old Beta version of the app that did use SMS in the [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) on Release management -> App release.

The Beta wasn't active any more but that old version was still showing under Release management -> Artifact library-> Active artifacts, so am guessing Google still considered it an active application. Helpfully this area also shows you all the permissions your app uses, in case you are concerned if a library or plugin is adding permissions without your knowledge.

[Removing the Beta version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420414/remove-obsolete-beta-version-from-google-play#52444794) and appealing the removal as it being due to an inactive Beta, got the app republished within a few hours.