# Android app suspended from Google play, can't get it reinstated

Tags: android, google-play, alipay

Google has apparently decided to crack down on usage of Chinese SDKs, because both a client and a colleague got their apps suspended from the Play Store for using an old version of a Chinese SDK*.

My client got the following email:

> Hi Developers at {company name},
>
> After review, {app name},
>   {app package}[Version:12725], has been removed from Google
>   Play because it violates our personal and sensitive information
>   policy. This app won’t be available to users until you submit a
>   compliant update.
>
> Here’s how you can submit your app for another review:
>
> Review the Personal and Sensitive Information policy and make the
>   necessary changes to your app. Make sure your app is compliant with
>   the User Data policy and all other policies listed in the Developer
>   Program Policies. Remember that additional enforcement could occur if
>   there are further policy issues with your apps. **Your app is using the
>   AliPay SDK which is uploading the users' phone number without proper
>   disclosure**. Make sure to also post a privacy policy in both the
>   designated field in the Play Developer Console and from within the
>   Play distributed app itself. Please upgrade AliPay SDK version to
>   15.5.5 or higher. Sign in to your Play Console and upload the modified, policy compliant APK. Make sure to increment the version
>   number of the APK. Submit your app.

The colleague got a very similar email regarding usage of an SDK by Xiaomi.

### TL;DR

We both quickly updated the apps according to Google's instructions and submitted new versions (with new versionName and versionCode).

It's been 3 days and 4 versions since and the apps were not reinstated to the store yet.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the distribution polices and operations of an app distribution channel, which [has been declared to be off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've opened a support ticket with Google and the support rep notified me once more that the offending version is 12725, the old obsolete version.

It turns out that the Beta track still had this version. Even though it was superseded by the production one, Google still won't publish my app.

I had to [Remove obsolete beta version from Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420414/remove-obsolete-beta-version-from-google-play) and the app was reinstated within the hour.

Same story with my colleague's app.