# How do I deactivate a specific app beta version on Android PlayStore?

Tags: android, google-play

I'd previously uploaded a beta app whose version code was 660000 (addressing a bug fix). If I want to push out a new beta version whose version code is lower than 660000, I can't do it, which I understand.

Now, I'd like to deactivate/remove the 660000 version from app store so that I can publish my new app. How do I do that? Documentation on google playstore is more or less not helpful in answering the question.

Comment: Version codes have to increase for every new version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate the current app in beta by pushing/uploading a new version of the app for beta release with version 660001 or higher. Another option is by promoting app in alpha to beta. if you have an alpha app you can promote the same to beta, which will also remove the current app (only if the version if the incoming from alpha higher than the existing one). I hope it solves your issue.

Comment: 660000 is in beta, how do I remove it?

Comment: You can't remove an app once uploaded...you have to release it or the only thing you can do is to unpublish it or as mentioned above replace it with another build of the app. To Unpublish the app you can go to Pricing and distribution -> Unpublish

Comment: Check this if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52444794/1994089

Comment: @vxr147 were you able to resolve your issue? Please provide a solution so that It can be helpful for the others in the community